# specifying group-level effects in brms

Tags: r, linear-regression, multilevel-analysis, brms, hierarchical-bayesian

I'm trying to model the effects of one continuous variable (mass) and three categorical variables (site, sex, and method) on another continuous variable with `brms`. The explanatory variables are to some degree nested, and these are the hypothesized relationships:

1. 'global' relationship between mass and y, as well as 'global' intercepts for the three continuous variables
2. site-specific relationship (intercept and slope) between mass and y
3. site- and sex-specific relationship (intercept and slope) between mass and y
4. site-specific intercepts for method.

My 'draft' model looks like this:

```
m <- brm(y ~ mass +                     # 1. slope for continuous variable
             site + sex + method +      # 1. intercepts for each categorial variable            
             (1 + mass | site) +        # 2. intercept & slope for mass nested in site
             (1 + mass | site + sex) +  # 3. intercept & slope nested in site & sex
             (1 | site + method),       # 4. intercept nested site & method
           family = gaussian(link = "identity"), data = df)
```

However, when I try to run this, I get the following error message:

```
Error: Duplicated group-level effects are not allowed.
Occured for effect 'Intercept' of group 'site'.
```

I know the issue is that site is included in this model multiple times, but I don't know how to rewrite this model to still include all of the hypothesized relationships I've described above.

Comment: What do you think `(1 + mass | site + sex)` should be doing? Perhaps you want `(1 + mass | site:sex)` to model the intercept and slope per combination of site and sex?

Comment: E.g. in `lmer` this doesn't even seem to be legal syntax: `lme4::lmer(hp ~ (1 | am + cyl), mtcars)` errors.

Comment: Agree with @Axeman, probably more generally your `(x + y | f + g)` terms should be `(x + y | f:g)`

Comment: Thanks @Axeman. That was the solution. If you want to write up an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is attributed to @Axeman and @ben-bolker.

The issue with the initial model is the syntax. Instead of `(1 + mass | site + sex)`, the correct line is `(1 + mass | site : sex)`, i.e., separate intercepts and slopes for each combination of site and sex.

```
m <- brm(y ~ mass +                     # 1. slope for continuous variable
             site + sex + method +      # 1. intercepts for each categorial variable            
             (1 + mass | site) +        # 2. intercept & slope for mass nested in site
             (1 + mass | site : sex) +  # 3. intercept & slope nested in site & sex
             (1 | site + method),       # 4. intercept nested site & method
           family = gaussian(link = "identity"), data = df)
```